# Probabilities computation for Naïve Bayes classifier under Weka

Tags: probability, weka, bayesian, document-classification

I want to understand how the Naive Bayes classifier works with text classification, in particular, how is the calculation of probabilities?

> ```
>                                    Class
> ```
>
> Attribute                                     event1            event2
>
> ## (0.4)                (0.6)

2006
  mean                                             1                    0
  std. dev.                                   0.1667               0.1667
  weight sum                                       1                    2
  precision                                        1                    1

in my data, I have two instances with class "event2" and one instance with class "event1". So normally the class probabilities should be as follows:
P(event1)=1/3=0.33 and P(event2)=2/3=0.66
But with Naive Bayes:
P(event1)=0.3 and P(event2)=0.6

I want to know also how it calculates the probability of the attribute "2006"

any help?

Comment: Before making an attempt to calculate it with Weka make sure you understand the concept of Naive Bayes text classification. See below for examples:http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf2b/learnSlides/inf2b12-learnlec07.pdf

Comment: Thanks  matcheek. It is an easy to understand tutorial. Now I want to know what is the model of Weka's Naive Bayes? is it Bernoulli Model or Multinomial model?

Comment: As far as I know (from experimenting, not from reading the code), the standard "NaiveBayes" algorithm is Bernoulli based, and "NaiveBayesMultinomial" (appearing in WEKA 3.7) is - naturally - multinomial.